# Error when uploading files Sharepoint CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

Trying to upload CSV file to our sharepoint (online) and I got this error:

> The Login server cannot issue the requested compact encrypted ticket
> because a Data Encryption Key (DEK) has not been uploaded to the site.

I'm using this code:

```
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://demoxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/FS_SI/"))
            {
                ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in @"myPass@123")
                    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("myEmail@gmail.com", securePassword);

                FileCreationInformation fcInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                fcInfo.Url = fileName;
                fcInfo.Overwrite = true;
                fcInfo.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(content);

                Web myWeb = ctx.Web;
                List myLibrary = myWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                myLibrary.RootFolder.Files.Add(fcInfo);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            };
```

Is it because I'm using my personal email (GMAIL)?

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint online, I suggest using the PnP.Framework AuthenticationManager ([details](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/blob/dev/docs/MigratingFromPnPSitesCore.md)). We use it to connect to SPO (with a client id and client secret; no passwords), and SharePoint 2019 (with service account username and password).

To use your gmail account, add the PnP.Framework NuGet package, and check the details in the linked article. You would need the Azure AD client id of your SPO site, and optionally, a client secret. With both, you wouldn't need any password. With just the client id, you could use your gmail account and secure password.

Client id & secret:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientID, clientSecret)) {...
```

This works for me.

With client id and username/password (never tried; example from article):

```
var authManager = new AuthenticationManager("<Azure AD client id>", "myEmail@gmail.com", securePassword);
using (ClientContext context = authManager.GetContext("https://demoxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/FS_SI/")) {...
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue from above question is user credential. I ask our sharepoint admin to create me a 365 user instead of my personal gmail.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).